# Java Generics, Type Erasure and Bounded Type Parameters

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a generic node class that will accept any type of object as its data. I define the class as

```
protected class Node<E> {
    E data;
    Node next;
    Node prev;

public Node(E element)
    {
      data = element;
      next = null;
      prev = null;
    }
    ...
}

public E getElement()
{
  return this.data; 
}
```

Later, I call the `getElement` method from a generic `MyLinkedList<E>` class, but get the compilation error

```
  Error: incompatible types
  required: E
  found:    java.lang.Object

public class DoublyLinkedList12<E> extends AbstractList<E> {

   private int nelems;
   private Node head;
   private Node tail;

   public DoublyLinkedList12()
   {
      head = new Node(null);
      tail = new Node(null);
      head.next = tail;
      tail.prev = head;
      nelems = 0;

   }
@Override
  public E next() throws NoSuchElementException
  {
    if(this.hasNext() == false){
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    left = right;
    right = right.getNext();
    forward = true;
    canRemove = true;
    idx++;
    return left.getElement(); // <== Error here
 }
```

I believe this is caused by generic type erasure, and I believe I need to use bounded parameters to avoid this. What class can I extend as to allow all types as data/is there a more efficient way to go about this? Thanks,

Comment: "from a generic MyLinkedList class" - you sure you used a generic `MyLinkedList`, as opposed to, say, forgetting the type parameters and getting a raw `MyLinkedList`?

Comment: You need to show the code for `MyLinkedList`. Most likely it is incorrect -- type erasure shouldn't cause this kind of failure.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are getting the error because you are doing something like this in `MyLinkedList<E>`:

```
E nextElement = node.getNext().getElement();
```

This doesn't work because you are using the [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `Node` for `next` and `prev`.

Use `Node<E>` instead.

To prevent this in the future, enable the javac compiler warnings, which would have given you these messages multiple times:

```
[rawtypes] found raw type: Node
  missing type arguments for generic class Node<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class Node

[unchecked] unchecked call to Node(E) as a member of the raw type Node
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class Node
```